# What is meant here while describing Newton's second law in this book?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, textbook-erratum

I was reading the book *Fundamental Laws of Mechanics* by I.E. Irodov and while he describes Newtonian laws of dynamics, he states the following statement

> The product of the mass of a mass point by its acceleration is a function of the position of this point relative to surrounding bodies, and sometimes a function of its velocity as well. This function is called a force.

Now, what I don't understand here is what he means when he says that force is **sometimes** a function of velocity. It should always be a function of velocity,shouldn't it.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No. Think about the force on an object near the earth's surface.

Comment: @Lewis Miller It would always be mass times the time derivative of velocity. Can you explain further...

Comment: $F=ma$. The origin of $F$ varies. In many cases (but not all), its a function of the location of $m$. In some cases, for example a charge moving in magnetic field, it's a function of the velocity of $m$.

Comment: See @freecharley answer below.

Comment: @Abhinav - You apparently are thinking that the time derivative of a function $f(t)$ is by definition a function of that function: $df(t)/dt = g(f(t))$. This is not the case.

Comment: @DavidHammen You're right... I thought exactly the same. Thanks for clearing this for me. I didn't thought much. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are forces on a mass point that are only position dependent, e.g. the gravitational force which is the negative gradient of the gravitational potential at a certain position. There are, however, forces that are dependent on the velocity of the mass, like e.g., the Stokes force (drag) exerted on the movement of a small sphere in a viscous fluid which is proportional to the velocity $v$ where $r$ is the sphere radius, $\eta$ the fluid viscosity $$\vec F_{drag}= -b\vec v=-6\pi \eta r \vec v$$ Another example is the Lorentz force exerted by a magnetic field $\vec B$ on a mass with charge $q$ and velocity $\vec v$ $$\vec F_{Lorentz}=q\vec v \times \vec B$$ Thus the force is not always a function of velocity, as the gravitational force law demonstrates, but it can be a function of the velocity in certain situation, as shown above.